# Problemas entre document.ready y turbo-links de ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, slider

MI problema es muy sencillo, tengo la necesidad de crear un carousel en 3d, pero para evitar eso decidi buscar uno de mi agrado y tratar de personalizarlo a mi gusto, ya funciona correctamente el que descargue, solo que no esta en ruby y decidi pasarlo a mi proyecto. pero al momento de traspasarlo no me salen errores, simplemente el carousel no funciona y las imagenes se quedan estaticas.

Codigo HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--
      Demo by Ildar Sagdejev ( http://twitter.com/tknomad )
    -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style>
      #showcase {
        height: 460px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- GitHub ribbon: http://codepo8.github.io/css-fork-on-github-ribbon/ -->
    <div class="wrap">
      <div id="showcase" class="noselect">
        <%= image_tag("1.jpg",:class=>"cloud9-item") %>
       <%= image_tag("2.jpg", :class=>"cloud9-item") %>
       <%= image_tag("3.jpg", :class=>"cloud9-item") %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/PaginaPrincipal/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/PaginaPrincipal/reflection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/PaginaPrincipal/cloud9.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        var showcase = $("#showcase"), title = $('#item-title')

        showcase.Cloud9Carousel( {
          yOrigin: 42,
          yRadius: 48,
          mirror: {
            gap: 12,
            height: 0.2
          },
          buttonLeft: $("#nav > .left"),
          buttonRight: $("#nav > .right"),
          autoPlay: 1,
          bringToFront: true,
          onRendered: rendered,
          onLoaded: function() {
            showcase.css( 'visibility', 'visible' )
            showcase.css( 'display', 'none' )
            showcase.fadeIn( 1500 )
          }
        } )

        function rendered( carousel ) {
          title.text( carousel.nearestItem().element.alt )

          // Fade in based on proximity of the item
          var c = Math.cos((carousel.floatIndex() % 1) * 2 * Math.PI)
          title.css('opacity', 0.5 + (0.5 * c))
        }


        $(document).keydown( function( e ) {
          //
          // More codes: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm
          //
          switch( e.keyCode ) {
            /* left arrow */
            case 37:
              $('#nav > .left').click()
              break

            /* right arrow */
            case 39:
              $('#nav > .right').click()
          }
        } )
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Codigo CSS:

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrap {
  width: 980px; /* fixed width, centered in viewport */
  left: -490px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap > h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#showcase img {
  cursor: pointer;
}


#get {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Tambien puse alerts en los .js que manda llamar y si me los ejecuta asi que no se muy bien que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, las imagenes se ven pero sin movimiento y totalmente planas.

Link de descarga de el codigo que funciona correctamente fuera de ruby, esta modificado.

```
https://mega.nz/#!8IExCaYB!dju-55XUVWt1GgVqQPO91Mmmo0LDyVOdlYf9Yb2m3Zo
```

**Actualizacion**

Realize la suspension temporal de los turbolinks para ver si eso me arreglaba el problema temporalmente, pero no arreglo nada, tambien puse el siguiente codigo:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  ...your javascript goes here...

});
```

Creo que ese codigo de arriba solo funciona para Rails 5.0 en adelante y yo uso esa version de rails.

COdigo que quite de turbo links

application.js

```
 //=require turbolinks
```

En views/layouts application.html.erb

`'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload`'

Si pongo un alert dentro de:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

     alert("Entro");

    });
```

No me sale el mensaje de la alerta.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código completo de `application.js`? Considerando que tienes _rails 5_, no deberías tener problema con `$(document).ready()`; ¿y cómo agregaste jquery a rails tu aplicación?

Answer (score 0):

prueba desactivar turbolink momentaniamente para descartar.

1. En tu application.js elimina //=require turbolinks
2. En views/layouts application.html.erb elimina en las referencias css y js el parámetro 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'

Lo que sucede es que la mayoría de las funciones definidas en tu js levantan después del conocido $(document).ready el cual no se lleva muy bien con turbolinks, yo tuve una experiencia similar a la tuya. Si es eso te recomiendo que te documentes sobre turbolinks ya que desactivarlo no es la mejor opción pues aumenta notablemente los tiempos de carga de tu app. Saludos

Comment: ya desabilite los turbolinks y aplique $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(). pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: si desabilitaste turbolinks no tienes que llamar la función de esa manera, fijate si en tu application.js tienes a jquery de primero en las referencias eso también influye